# Validate username field in user registration form, drupal 7

Tags: forms, hooks

I need to compare the text in the username field with the text in email field of the registration form. If they are not equal i want to stop the registration. I think i should use a hook but i really don't know where to start from.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by using [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) and adding an extra validation function to the user register form:

```
function MYMODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#validate'][] = 'MYMODULE_validate_register_form';
}

function MYMODULE_validate_register_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['values']['mail'] != $form_state['values']['name']) {
    form_set_error('name', t('Name and email must be the same.'));
  }
}
```

I'm not 100% positive those `$form_state['values']` keys are the right ones so you'll need to inspect the form to make sure; but the logic is the same either way.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the Email registration module is something for you: 
http://drupal.org/project/email_registration

> Allow users to register and login using only an email address. Users
>   can then log-in using their email address and password for
>   authentication.

Comment: I looked into that module but i think it could create some mess with the site. Since it is already up & running i don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: The module just put's the given email address into the user name field. So if this is your current policy, this shouldn't be a problem. Of course you should test this kind of changes on a dev environment before putting it into production.

Comment: There is a half mess in that site and i don't want to create a bigger one... using a hook seems to be the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 2):

Clive's answer above is great, but if you prefer to work in the theme layer you can put this code into your theme's template.php file.

```
function MYTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form'){
    $form['#validate'][] = 'MYTHEME_validate_register_form';
  }
}

function MYTHEME_validate_register_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['values']['mail'] != $form_state['values']['name']) {
    form_set_error('name', t('Name and email must be the same.'));
  }
}
```

You can obviously change the validation statement to do whatever you want, you just have to make sure to pass "form_set_error()" to invalidate the form and display a message to the end user.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Login Toboggon](https://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module to do all kinds of neat login-y things.

> The LoginToboggan module offers several modifications of the Drupal
>   login system in an external module by offering the following features
>   and usability improvements:
>
> - Allow users to login using either their username OR their e-mail address.
> - Allow users to login immediately.
> - Provide a login form on Access Denied pages for non-logged-in (anonymous) users.
> - The module provides two login block options: One uses JavaScript to display the form within the block immediately upon clicking "log in".
>     The other brings the user to a separate page, but returns the user to
>     their original page upon login.
> - Customize the registration form with two e-mail fields to ensure accuracy.
> - Optionally redirect the user to a specific page when using the 'immediate login' feature.
> - Optionally redirect the user to a specific page upon validation of their e-mail address.
> - Optionally display a user message indicating a successful login.
> - Optionally combine both the login and registration form on one page.
> - Optionally have unvalidated users purged from the system at a pre-defined interval (please read the CAVEATS section of INSTALL.txt
>     for important information on configuring this feature!).
> - Integrates with Rules module to do various tasks when a user validates via email validation process (see
>     http://drupal.org/node/880904 for an example)